# How to Declare servicestack RestService with list of objects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, servicestack

I need to pass multiple objects from my application to the rest service that is using servicestack. I need to do something like this

```
EventLogService : RestServiceBase<List<EventLogData>>
```

It is not giving any build error. But the name of operation is listed as "List`1" instead of the name given.
I have this line of code to declare AppHost()

```
public AppHost() : base("Rest WCF", typeof(EventLogService).Assembly) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AppHost is used to register **all** your services, not just one of them. ServiceStack will scan through and **register all services** defined in the Assembly:  `typeof(EventLogService).Assembly`. Likewise the "Rest WCF" name doesn't refer to a single web service, it's refers to all of them and is used on the autogenerated metadata pages.

You **should** have a Request DTO for each of your services, so if you want to pass in a `List<EventLogData>` you can do this with:

```
 public class EventLogs : List<EventLogData> {}
```

or

```
 public class EventLogs {
     public List<EventLogData> Items { get; set; }
 }
```